# javascript hover one element to change text color of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I feel that I am getting close but am new to javascript.
Is there anything wrong with this code. I want when you hover on element "research_arrow" to change the text color of "research_link".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".research_arrow").hover(function () {
    $(".research_link").css("color:#ffffff");
  });
  $(".research_arrow").mouseleave(function () {
     $(".research_link").css("color:#000000");
  });
});
```

Comment: try `.css('color', '#fff')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".research_arrow").hover(function() {
     $(".research_link").css("color", "#ffffff");
  }, function() {
     $(".research_link").css("color", "#000000");
  });
});
```

hover accepts two function one like mouseover and other like mouse out.

Answer (score 4):

You're using object notation, in which case, you need `{}`

```
css({color:"#ffffff"});
```

Or if you just want to set one property:

```
css("color", "#ffffff");
```

Answer (score 1):

hover should take two functions as arguments, the first being the "mouseenter" function and the second being "mouseleave".  So your function should be changed to this:

```
$(".research_arrow").hover(function () {
    $(".research_link").css("color", "#ffffff");
}, function () {
    $(".research_link").css("color", "#000000");
});
```

or just using mouseenter and mouseleave:

```
$(".research_arrow").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".research_link").css("color", "#ffffff");
});
$(".research_arrow").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".research_link").css("color", "#000000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".research_arrow").hover(function () {
    $(".research_link").css("color","#ffffff");
});
$(".research_arrow").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".research_link").css("color","#000000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic [demo/example](http://jsfiddle.net/9sRp8/2/)...

```
$('.foo').hover(function () {
    $('.bar').css('color', 'blue');
}, function () {
    $('.bar').css('color', 'black');    
});
```

or using an object...

```
$('.foo').hover(function () {
    $('.bar').css({'color': 'blue'});
}, function () {
    $('.bar').css({'color': 'black'});    
});
```

Comment: This won't change the color back to black

Comment: I just think a more generic answer would include a second function as argument to `hover()` to change the color back.